# Error while doing apt update

Tags: apt, dpkg, nas

I have to say I'm quite new to Linux, but I'm trying to create a small NAS by following a guide for this.

I got to a point in which the guide tells me to install "Webmin" and I couldn't preform this action (specifically `libnet­-ssleay-­perl`). So I checked google on how to do it and from there I got stuck because I can't use the `apt update` command.
At this point I tried using: https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-find-and-fix-broken-packages-on-linux/ for help and got to the `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq` but it requests a file name and I'm lost because I don't know what I'm supposed to give it.
The Error I receive for apt update is:

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i'

E: Sub-process returned and error code
```

Edit:
The OS I'm running is "Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"

Link to the tutorial I follow: https://quidsup.net/downloads/CreatingaNASwithUbuntuServer.pdf

And for the Error for webmin, it doesn't show anymore. all of the commands passed.

Comment: If you follow a tutorial it would be helpful to have a link. Most important would also be that you provide your OS details. It would be good to know which action you're performing and the full error message to it (The original one to install webmin, not what you think would fix it), Please edit your question.

Comment: That doesn't look like the complete output of `apt-get update`. Please edit your question to include the complete message.

Comment: "for the Error for webmin, it doesn't show anymore" --> Then please, try again this step and tell us about the error then.

Comment: Btw: The [tutorial is from "14 Nov 2013"](https://quidsup.net/dl/). That is probably also the source of your issues. it is written for older version of Ubuntu (server).  You should search for a more recent tutorial. Or use some complete NAS OS suite like [OpenMediaVault](https://www.openmediavault.org) or [TrueNas Core](https://www.truenas.com/truenas-core/).

Comment: @pLumo I wrote that the Error doesn't show anymore, this is why I can't copy it to the post. Otherwise I would have.
I think that I will try one of your suggestions for NAS, I didn't consider that the versions would be the problem.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Open a terminal. Run `sudo apt update`. Copy/paste the output into your question. Use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code)